# Sitecore 9 - Workflow not working without Lock and Edit

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc, sitecore9

In Sitecore 8.1 editors, reviewer and publisher are able to submit, approve and publish content without selecting lock and edit for an item. I want same to happen in Sitecore 9.

In sitecore 9, option (submit, approve, reject and publish) are frozen.

Answer (score 0):

This is a desired behavior post Sitecore 8.1 update 3. Check [this](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/13670/change-in-work-flow-state-disables-workflow-command-in-quick-actions-or-gutter-p/14640#14640) answer if it helps!

Comment: Yes exactly. I was able to find the answer but dint updated here. I refereed to the Sitecore releases notes  

https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/Sitecore%2081/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2081%20Update3/Release%20Notes